# Android - Get size of TextView content

Tags: android, textview, size, dimension

I currently have TextViews containing HTML content, including different sized text and images.

The TextViews are aligned to other views in such a way that only three lines of the content is shown to the user.

Is there anyway to get the height the TextViews would take up if they were expanded to the size of their content?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:
TextView.getLayout().getHeight();

Comment: Thank you! All my phrasing on Google did me no good, but this is what I was looking for.